# Difference between serialization and normal object storage?

Tags: java, c#, oop, serialization

*Serialization is the process of converting an object stored in memory into a stream of bytes to be transferred over a network, stored in a DB, etc.*

But isn't the object already stored in memory as bits and bytes? Why do we need another process to convert the object stored as bytes into another byte representation? Can't we just transmit the object directly over the network?

I think I may be missing something in the way the objects are stored in memory, or the way the object fields are accessed.

Can someone please help me in clearing up this confusion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different systems don't store things in memory in the same way. The obvious example is endianness.

Serialization defines a way by which systems using different in-memory representations can communicate.

Another important fact is that the requirements on in-memory and serialized data may be different: when in-memory, fast read (and maybe write) access is desirable; when serialized, small size is desirable. It is easier to create two different formats to fit these two use cases than it is to create one format which is good for both.

An example which springs to mind is `LinkedHashMap`: this basically stores two versions of the mapping when in memory (one to capture insertion order; one as a traditional hash map). However, you don't need both of these representations to reconstruct the same map from a serialized form: you only need the insertion order of key/value pairs. As such, the serialized form does not store the same data as the in-memory form.

Comment: So are the serialization algorithms implemented the same way in all the languages? For example, Serialization library in both Java and C# will work the same way to convert the object into the same endian form? Is there a standard for Serialization then?

Comment: There are several standards used for serialisation, for example look at JSON or XML.

Comment: There is no single way of serializing data. Even within a single language, there could be any number of ways to serialize the same data; Java's built-in serialization (in the sense of classes implementing `Serializable`) is just one way of doing it.

Comment: I understand the difference now. I assumed(silly me!) that the streams of bytes got after serializing an object were also in some endian form. But that stream is a simple byte representation of the object. It depends on the end-system how it stores those bytes(big or little-endian). Endianness comes into picture while memory allocation. Thanks @AndyTurner!

Comment: @chaudharyp yes, but please don't take my answer as being limited to *just* endianness. It can include other things like field alignment, i.e. padding structures in memory for faster access.

Answer (score 2):

Serialization turns the pre-existing bytes from the memory into a universal form.

This is done because different systems allocate memory in different ways. Thus, we cannot ensure that the object can be saved directly from the memory on one machine and then be loaded back in properly into another, different machine.

Mabe you can find more information on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html) of Oracle docs.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of **object serialization** from book *Thinking In Java*.

> When you create an object, it exists for as long as you need it, but under no circumstances does it exist when the program terminates. While this makes sense at first, there are situations in which it would be incredibly useful if an object could exist and hold its information even while the program wasn’t running. Then, the next time you started the program, the object would be there and it would have the same information it had the previous time the program was running. Of course, you can get a similar effect by writing the information to a file or to a database, but in the spirit of making everything an object, it would be quite convenient to declare an object to be "persistent," and have all the details taken care of for you.
>
> Java’s object serialization allows you to take any object that implements the Serializable interface and turn it into a sequence of bytes that can later be fully restored to regenerate the original object. This is even true across a network, which means that the serialization mechanism automatically compensates for differences in operating systems. That is, you can create an object on a Windows machine, serialize it, and send it across the network to a Unix machine, where it will be correctly reconstructed. You don’t have to worry about the data representations on the different machines, the byte ordering, or any other details.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go with that set of mind : we take the object as is , and we send it as byte array over the network. another socket/httphandler receives that byte array.

now, two things come to mind:

1. ho much bytes to send?
2. what are these bytes? what class do these btyes represent?

you will have to provide this data as well. so for this action alone we need extra 2 steps.

Now, in C# and Java, as opposed to C++, the objects are scattered throught the heap, each object hold references to the objects it containes , so now we have another requirement

3. recursivly "catch" all the inner object and pack them into the byte array

now we get packed byte array which represent some object hirarchy, we need to tell the other side how to de-pack this byte array back to object+the object it holds so

4. Send information on how to unpack that byte array to object hirarchy

Some entities a obejct have cannot be sent over the net, such as functions. so now we have yet another step

5. Strip away things that cannot be serialized, like functions

this process goes on and one, for every new solution you will find many problems. Serialization is the process of taking that byte array you are talking about and making it something that can be handled in other enviroments, like network/files.